# NLog doesn't load Rules from XML configuration

Tags: c#, logging, nlog

Configuration file (except variables) contains data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="false">

  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Extended" />
  </extensions>

  <targets async="True">
    <target name="TraceLogger"
            type="File"
            fileName="${TraceFullPath}"
            archiveFileName="${TraceArchiveFullPath}"
            maxArchiveFiles="100"
            archiveNumbering="Sequence"
            archiveEvery="None"
            layout="${message}" />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*"
            minLevel="Trace"
            writeTo="TraceLogger"
            enabled="True" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Test execution code is:

```
    var configuration = new XmlLoggingConfiguration(configurationPath);
    var factory = new LogFactory(configuration);
    var logger = factory.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    logger.Trace("Message");
```

Debugger shows next properties values for:

```
configuration.base.LogginRules: Count = 0
configuration.base.AllTargets: Count = 0
logger.Is...Enabled = false (for all levels)
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try setting `throwExceptions` to `true`. There might be something wrong with your .config.

Comment: unfortunately, not :( . I googled NLog troubleshooting and went through steps to locate an error and logger start work perfect, even my changes with variables and targets

Answer (score 2):

Problem was simple: case-sensitive typo in variables and target value
I am sorry that took your time